# CSS dropdown menu problems and positioning

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having some problems with a css dropdown menu that I've been working on.

Here is a link to the site: rpg.vacau.com

There are 2 problems:

1. When you hover over the cog wheel, it not only drops down a small menu, but it drops down a black bar that takes up the rest of the space to the right.
2. The cog wheel is right next to the title, and I want it on the right side without absolute positioning, because the menu is relatively positioned.

So pretty much, how do I fix that weird black bar that drops down along with the menu, and how do I move the cog wheel and menu to the right side? Thanks in advance, and hope this makes sense.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Lite RPG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/web.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fonts.css" />
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="title" href="#">iON»</a></li>
        <li><a id="settings" href="#"><img src="/images/settings.png" height="20"
width="20" /></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

web.css

```
body, ul { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 65px;
    font-family: "Champagne & Limousines";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #292929;
}

nav #title {
    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

nav #settings {
    top: 0px;
    left: 1000px;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following 2 conditions in your CSS file

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    clear: both; 
}
```

And to the `li` you want to send to right, add a `float: right;` CSS rule. Eg:

`<li style="float: right;">`

**EDIT**

To keep the icon highlighted while the mouse is inside submenu,

```
nav li:hover #menu {
    background-color: #292929;
}
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks SO much!!! I had been struggling with this all day, and wasn't quite sure what was wrong :P

Comment: Also, is it possible to make the icon in the top-right corner stay highlighted as long as the cursor is over the menu?

Comment: Sweet man! I wish I could up vote you some more, but I can't yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Just give a `float: right` to the `LI`.

```
<li style="float: right;">
```

Check out the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This adds a horizontal scrollbar